# Configure Data Power MFP 8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, ibm-datapower

I'm trying to configure a Data Power on Mobile First Platform 8.0 installed in a WAS ND 8.5.x. with a cluster with 2 servers.

As I did on Mobile First Platform 7.1, I would like to change the access port with the property 'publicWorkLightPort' but this property has changed in MFP 8.0 and I don't know how is it called now or how is supposed to be in MFP 8.0

Comment: DataPower with LTPA integration: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/17/datapower-integration/

Comment: DataPower as an authorization server: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_datapower_as_authorization_server.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That property as well as the file that contains it (worklight.properties) is no longer used in MobileFirst Foundation 8.0. The port used by MobileFirst Server is defined in the application server's server.xml file.